# Obtaining unique values with different keys

Tags: php, arrays

after processing a CSV file I end up with a data structure like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Supplier Name] => John Lewis
            [Supplier Name2] => Fenwicks
            //other data
        )
    //Other elements
)
```

What I am trying to do is obtain all of the unique sluppliers.  The problem is, if there is more than one supplier in the array, a number is added to the end of it e.g. Supplier Name2.
What I have at the moment is this.

```
$suppliers = array();
foreach($csvArray as $k => $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $suppliers[] = $csvArray[$k]['Supplier Name'];
    }
}
$uniqueSuppliers = array_unique($suppliers);
```

Now that returns all unique values where the key is Supplier Name.  However, this does not take into affect Supplier Name2, 3, 4 etc.  Is there any way I can include anything that starts with Supplier Name within this search?

Thanks

Comment: try this $suppliers[] = $value instead of this  $suppliers[] = $csvArray[$k]['Supplier Name'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the key in `$key`, just test if it begins with `Supplier Name`

```
foreach ($csvArray as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, 'Supplier Name') === 0) {
            $suppliers[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when using strpos, make sure to use strict comparison `===`, because `false == 0` in php.